# How to include .h with makefile in linux?

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing software for ARM microcontrollers in C using linux and I'm not using an IDE. The reason for this is to learn how really low level stuff works. Now I want to include a `.h` file that has a corresponding `.c` file, in my `main.c` program the "usual way" by writing `#include "timer.h"`. This of course requires me to somehow change the Makefile and or linkerscript!?

How can I do this?

Right now the file `timer.h` is included, but directly in the Makefile like this:

```
LD=arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy

CFLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g -std=c99 -Wall
LDFLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g -lgcc -lc -lcs3 -lcs3unhosted -lefm32gg -Llib
ASFLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g
LINKERSCRIPT=lib/efm32gg.ld

polling.bin : polling.elf
    ${OBJCOPY} -O binary $< $@

polling.elf : polling.o timer.o dac.o gpio.o interrupt_handlers.o
    ${LD} -T ${LINKERSCRIPT} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} 

%.o : %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

.PHONY : pretty
pretty :
    -indent *.c *.h

.PHONY : upload
upload :
    -eACommander.sh -r --address 0x00000000 -f "polling.bin" -r

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm -rf *.o *.elf *.bin *.hex
```

Comment: http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html

Comment: That link describes a somewhat outdated method.  Try http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: You say _timer.h is included, but directly in the Makefile_ but I don't see any reference to `timer.h` in your makefile.  You don't have to change linker scripts due to headers, at least not typically.  As for adding a header as a prerequisite so that make will rebuild your code when it changes, you can just add `main.o: timer.h` to tell make that the `main.o` file depends on `timer.h`.  The links in the comments above will show you (more complex) ways to have make itself track prerequisites if you don't want to add them to the makefile by hand.

Comment: I'm seriously inexperienced on dealing with linker scripts, makefiles, object files etc. I only did it with IDEs, but I know that it is included. Maybe this happens in the linker script or with the `timer.o` object file? I appreciate the link, I'm reading up on it! Btw, initially there was no header file, only `.c` file. So no, the header file isn't really included, but the `.c` file is.

Comment: You put a dependency in the makefile describing which module depends on what header like this: `main.o: timer.h` Please read a make tutorial.